# Why does row number need to be passed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to have an example on managing geometry inside of frames independently and wrote the below code to have a checkered flag-like looking GUI.

import tkinter as tk

```
# a class that has 2 columns of frames inside
class TwoFrames(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)

        # creates 2 frame objects and passes self as parent, which
        # means object created using TwoFrames class is the parent
        self.frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame2 = tk.Frame(self)

        #manages 2 frames geometry
        self.frame1.grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frame2.grid(column=1, sticky="nsew")

        # enables resizing for 0th row, and 1st and 2nd columns of an
        # object of this class
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self, 1, weight=1)


class TwoLabels(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, color=True):
        super().__init__(master)

        #creates 2 Label objects with TwoLabels object as parent
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self)

        # configures the background color of labels for demonstrative
        # purposes
        if color:
            #label1 will have red color
            self.label1.configure(bg="black")
            #label2 will have blue color
            self.label2.configure(bg="white")
        else:
            #label1 will have blue color
            self.label1.configure(bg="white")
            #label2 will have red color
            self.label2.configure(bg="black")


        # manages the geometry
        self.label1.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.label2.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")

        # enables resizing like above, but this time for 2 rows and 1
        # column
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self, 1, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)


# creates the mainWindow
mainWindow = tk.Tk()

# creates a mainFrame that has 2 frames in it
mainFrame = TwoFrames(mainWindow)

# manages geometry of mainFrame and display it
mainFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# creates row_labels1 and row_labels2, both has 2 colored labels inside
row_labels1 = TwoLabels(mainFrame.frame1, True)
row_labels2 = TwoLabels(mainFrame.frame2, False)

# manages geometry of labels inside frames and displays them
row_labels1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
row_labels2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# run the application
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

But ironically, the code instead produced a checkered flag that has its one vertical half on a second row, as if what I'm trying to do is not possible. Later on I changed the;

```
#manages 2 frames geometry
self.frame1.grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.frame2.grid(column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

part with

```
#manages 2 frames geometry
self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.frame2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

and it worked as I first intended. I'm glad it works but;

- I'm not sure if the geometry is being managed on at least the class
  basis or not. Is it?
- What does passing, that I assumed to be equal to what I pass anyway,
  row numbers change?

Also I'd be glad if you could review my code in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/179067/152065).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if the geometry is being managed on at least the class basis or not. Is it?

Geometry management never is managed on a class basis. Geometry management is based on a parent/child structure of the widgets themselves. If widgets in a class are children of the class (eg: the class is a frame), then yes, the management can be seen as being done on a class basis. Tkinter doesn't know or care about your class structure, it only cares about widget parent/child relationships.

> What does passing, that I assumed to be equal to what I pass anyway, row numbers change?

Your assumption is false. If you don't specify a row, it is auto-incremented by one each time you call `grid`.

In other words, this:

```
self.frame1.grid(column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.frame2.grid(column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

... is functionally identical to this (pay close attention to the value for `row` in each line):

```
self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.frame2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
```

Although if you don't specify a column, it is by default equal to 0 even after you call `grid` multiple times. In other words:

```
self.label1.grid(row=0, sticky="nsew")
self.label2.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew")
```

is functionally identical to this (pay attention to `column` in each line):

```
self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")
self.label2.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="nsew")
```

As a rule of thumb (and for the sake of clarity) you should always supply both the row and column number. Doing so removes all ambiguity of where a widget is positioned.

Comment: I meant I assumed it would be 0 as it would start from 0 in the TwoFrames class, so I assumed it would be okay to not pass row numbers. I did the same assumption you're saying that they're identical. But it works apparently different, meaning that somehow they're not identical. I'm wondering how are those(the two grid options you're saying identical) different?

Comment: @Nae: the first one defaults to zero, but the second one defaults to 1. You are assuming both grid calls use a row of zero, but they do not. Each time you call `grid` it increments the row if you don't explicitly set a row.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the difference in your code. Sorry. But then how come TwoLabels class functions as I intended it to have, as its geometry is written similarly but this time with column numbers not passed?

Comment: @Nae: because in `TwoLabels` you are explicitly setting the rows. Because you don't explicitly set the columns, they default to 0 and 1.

Comment: I thought so too, but I tried setting both `column=0` they worked as they first did, yet when I try setting first label's column to 0 and second's to 1 it works differently, and for the argument of disproving what you're saying.

Comment: @Nae: I'm sorry, I misspoke in my comments. This is the problem with trying to explain things in the comment section. The column defaults to zero for every new row. So, you should get exactly the same behavior if you omit setting the column, or if you explicitly set the column to zero for every row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157825/discussion-between-nae-and-bryan-oakley).